# Android Studio Error "lint-gradle-api-26.1.2 not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run my App, AS comes up with this error. Says that the file was not found at https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar?referrer. Please help! Putting google() repo doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your build script look like? What's the stacktrace of the error? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Doesn't work means that error is still lingering around. I am using Jasonette and wanted to test its original app. The link is here: https://github.com/Jasonette/JASONETTE-Android/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I ran into this issue as well.  Basically, the issue is that mentioned jar file is no longer in jcenter.  I resolved by changing the order of search in our app build.gradle:


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```